# SQL UPDATE if condition (from other table) is true

Tags: php, mysql, sql

SHORT: I want to update a table if the userlevel is 1.

Only certain users (on the website) can update the table in the database.
Those users have a 'userlevel 1'

On the website the users are logged-in. 
The log-in information + the `userlevel` is in table `users`

The table I want to update is `device_data`

My query:

```
UPDATE table1 
SET colum1 = value1
WHERE deviceid = deviceid
INNERJOIN table2 ON table1
IF userlevel = '1'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE table1  firsttable 
INNER JOIN table2 secondtable
ON firsttable.deviceid = secondtable.deviceid   
SET firsttable.colum1 = secondtable.value1   
where secondtable.userlevel = '1'
```

You can try above code.

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

Use below query :

```
  UPDATE table1  SET colum1 = value1
  FROM table2 T2 
  WHERE T2.deviceid = table1.deviceid AND userlevel = '1'
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
UPDATE device_data a
inner join users b
on a.deviceid = b.deviceid 
SET a.column1 = 'value1'
WHERE b.userlevel = 1
```